# "No route to host" from different machines

Tags: networking, server, 22.04

I have 2 computers on the same network with different behavior for accessing a domain name. I'm trying to resolve (no pun intended) a "no route to host" issue. How can I have all domains resolve equally on both machines?

Here's an example of what's going on:

**Machine A**: Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with wired ethernet

```
curl plex.tv
Moved Permanently%
```

Connection worked and redirect returned as expected.

**Machine B**: Ubuntu 22.04 server with wifi connection

```
curl plex.tv
curl: (7) Failed to connect to plex.tv port 80 after 12287 ms: No route to host
```

Curiously, if I do the same test with [www.plex.tv](http://www.plex.tv) it works fine on both. Here's a table with behavior for different test domains:

| Domain | Machine A | Machine B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| plex.tv | works | no route to host |
| [www.plex.tv](http://www.plex.tv) | works | works |
| npr.org | works | no route to host |
| cnn.com | works | works |
| youtube.tv | works | works |

Here is the `ip address` and `ip route` output for each machine:

**Machine A**

```
ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:2b:67:c1:fe:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:7e:ea:71:a1:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.68/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 75351sec preferred_lft 75351sec
    inet6 2600:1700:37a8:c210::42/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3080sec preferred_lft 3080sec
    inet6 2600:1700:37a8:c210:a993:2446:f944:f1bb/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3141sec preferred_lft 3141sec
    inet6 2600:1700:37a8:c210:571d:2f99:79e0:7142/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3141sec preferred_lft 3141sec
    inet6 fe80::1d11:11ad:dd77:72c0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:94:ed:df:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

...

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.68 metric 600
```

**Machine B**

```
ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:7a:91:27:7c:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.73/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:1700:37a8:c210::40/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1973sec preferred_lft 1973sec
    inet6 2600:1700:37a8:c210:7e7a:91ff:fe27:7c0c/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3589sec preferred_lft 3589sec
    inet6 fe80::7e7a:91ff:fe27:7c0c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

...

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.73
```

I know there are plenty of config details involved here, but I'm not sure what is useful. I'm happy to update this post per advice to debug, please just let me know what's most useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default gateway is different for your computer settings **A** and **B**. This should definitely not be if they are both in the same LAN and the same broadcast domain.

Compare:

**Machine A**

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

**Machine B**

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static
```

It also differs in that the **A** has a gateway assigned using DHCP and the **B** has a gateway set up manually.

It seems to me that it is a miracle that B communicates at all. Perhaps this is due to the ICMP redirect packets that the 192.168.1.1 node sends to the **B** to inform it that **B** is using the wrong gateway. But that's just my speculation. You will see the reality when you turn on Wireshark on B and explore communication.

**My advice:**

Correct the settings on **B** so that the computer has all the parameters assigned using DHCP.

I do not rule out that the cause is in something else.

Comment: This was indeed the trouble; thank you! I'm not longer relying on miracles and things function as expected.

Comment: When you provided the correct data, it was possible to find the problem. Thank you for the evaluation.